# overload two methods with vararg and String[] parameter

Tags: java

I want overload two method with one parameter, in a method `varargs` of String and another `String[]` but I achieve following compilation-time error:

```
Duplicate method registerByName(String...)
```

My snippet code is:

```
public void registerByName(String[] names)
{

}

public void registerByName(String...names)
{

}
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vararg` is another way to place `(Object[])` so a Method `MyMethod(MyObject[] obj)` and `MyMethod(MyObject... obj)` are the same to compiler. It's just syntactic sugar.

You could refer the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

> It is still true that multiple arguments must be passed in an array, but the varargs feature automates and hides the process. Furthermore, it is upward compatible with preexisting APIs. So, for example, the MessageFormat.format method now has this declaration:
>
> ```
> public static String format(String pattern,
>                             Object... arguments);
> ```
>
> The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the **final argument may be passed as an array or as a sequence of arguments**. [...]

Answer (score 2):

"String..." and "String[]" are exactly one thing...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method like

```
public static void registerByName(String... names);
```

It is perfectly legal to call it with an array argument:

```
registerByName(new String[] {"sam"});
```

For this reason, you can't overload with `Type[]` and `Type...`.

The JVM doesn't even know the difference between these two signatures. Try running `javap` on a class file with a varargs method.

Comment: I don't know if that is a good explanation. You can call a `foo(Integer x)` with an `int` argument, too, but still overload the method in both variations, so this reasoning does not always work. (The last sentence of the answer is more like it).